# How to transfer Anaconda env installed on one machine to server?

Tags: python, pyspark, conda, spark-submit

Is there any way to transfer/copy my existing env (which has everything already installed) to the server?

```
$ conda env export > environment.yaml
```

- I have used above command to create .yaml file
- Can any one please tell how i can use this file on server side?

---

```
spark-submit --properties-file config.properties --jars /home/PycharmProjects/spark-excel_2.11-0.11.1.jar,/home/PycharmProjects/mongo-spark-connector_2.11-2.4.1.jar /home/PycharmProjects/NewConnection.py 9dhd38910242a7b9793ed3
```

1. Using above command to run on local system by activating conda environment.
2. So my next step is to run the same code on server side

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First we need to pack conda env by using below command

1. Activate your conda env which you want to pack and then use below command

   ```
   (your_conda_env) vishal@vishal-linux:~$ conda pack -n your_conda_env
   ```

- After packing your env it will create "your_conda_env.tar.gz" folder
- You can move this folder on sever(or any other machine) and use below command to run your spark job

  `PYSPARK_PYTHON=/home/vishal/your_conda_env/bin/python spark-submit --properties-file config.properties --jars /home/PycharmProjects/spark-excel_2.11-0.11.1.jar,/home/PycharmProjects/mongo-spark-connector_2.11-2.4.1.jar /home/PycharmProjects/NewConnection.py 9dhd38910242a7b9793ed3`